# ¿Cómo reemplazar un valor determinado por NULL en una consulta mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Imagen de la consulta]¿Cómo dejo de mostrar un valor `0` que va añadido a una fecha en MySQL desde un `SELECT`? ambos tendrían que ser `NULL`.

Ej:

```
Campo1 = 0 CampoFecha = dd/mm/aaaa
```

y quiero que sea así

```
Campo1 = NULL CampoFecha = NULL
```

La consulta es:

```
SELECT uni_secciones.codigo AS 'seccion',
       uni_curimp.facta,
       uni_notas.recupera,
       uni_curimp.frec
  FROM uni_notas
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! ☺ No olvides visitar el [recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender más acerca de este sitio. Tu pregunta, tal como está redactada, es confusa. Sería de más utilidad si agregaras la consulta SQL completa. Puedes editar tu pregunta [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/20311/edit).

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, Cris. ¿Pretendes que el `Campo1` se muestre en `null` solo cuando la fecha es `null` y el campo 1 es cero, o quieres que `Campo1` se muestre en `null` solo cuando `Campo1` sea `0` sin importar el valor de la fecha?. De manera general, cuando preguntes sobre consultas SQL es buena idea incluir una muestra de los datos de la(s) tabla(s) sobre los que vas a operar y una muestra de cómo quieres ver la salida.

Comment: Otra es que tu pregunta está etiquetada mySQL y Oracle (a la vez), pero son motores diferentes y por lo general, la solución es diferente. Si buscas una solución que aplique para varios motores, es buena idea que lo aclares en el cuerpo de la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias fijate que quiero cargar los datos de un pfd desde PHP en forma de una tabla, sin embargo al momento de que ejecuto mi consulta la cual adjuntare me tira ciertos valores que se ingresaron por error y para que esto quede validado quiero que la consulta me reemplace los valores de 0 y la fecha en valores vacíos o valores nulos.

Comment: Mi consulta es la siguiente: 
**select uni_secciones.codigo as 'seccion',
                                               uni_curimp.facta,
                                               uni_notas.recupera,
                                               uni_curimp.frec                                            
                                        from uni_notas**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT campo0,
       CASE
         WHEN Campo1 = '0' THEN null
       END,
       CASE 
         WHEN CampoFecha = '0' THEN null
       END
  FROM tu_tabla;
```

y funcionaria.

Comment: Gracias, me ha sido muy útil. :)

Comment: Cris, si esta respuesta te ha servido para resolver tu pregunta, te sugiero que la marques como aceptada para que los demás usuarios (que pueden tener tu misma duda) encuentren aquí la respuesta fácilmente. @CrisValdez